# Passing Model id on Ajax.Actionlink OnSuccess to another Javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I can't seem to figuire out the correct syntax. Seem to have tried everything:

```
@model User

...

@Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "AddUser",new {id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "post",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "dialog-add-user",
OnSuccess = **"function(){ AddUserShow(" + @Model.Id + ");}",**
OnFailure = "userFailure"
}
```

On success I simply need to pass my userId to a further Javascript method. Nothing seems to work. I looked around here and found some suggestions but still no luck.
I tried:

```
 "new Function('AddUserShow(" + @Model.Id + ")')",
 "function(){ AddUserShow(" + @Model.Id + ");}",
 "function(){ AddUserShow(this," + @Model.Id + ");}",

 Also tried sticking the user ID in a hidden field to try and pass it later from functions above instead of accessing @Model:
 "AddUserShow($('#Id').val()))",
```

Code at the receiving end:

```
function AddUserShow(id)
{
 alert(id);
}
```

Id that's being passed is a Guid if it matters.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes in there, otherwise javascript will be trying to interpret your Id as a variable.

```
"AddUserShow(" + @Model.Id + ");" // bad. becomes AddUserShow(123abc);
"AddUserShow('" + @Model.Id + "');" // good! becomes AddUserShow('123abc');
```

Comment: OnSuccess = "function(){ AddUserShow(' " + @Model.Id + " ');}",

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Expected identifier" :(

Comment: Can you share exactly what the output is?

Comment: Model.Id is a GUID. I added it to op.

Comment: Can you view source or use a script debugger to see the actual javascript that gets output by your code? Where the runtime error is occuring?

Comment: Got it. You were correct. Having function(){} in the front wasn't necessarily at all.
Just calling AddUserShow directly with single quotes worked.
Thanks again.